# ParseException: extraneous input 'STRING' expecting {')', ',', 'CONSTRAINT'}

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

while creating a delta table im getting parse exception error:
ParseException:  extraneous input 'STRING' expecting {')', ',', 'CONSTRAINT'}

csv file includes the column names and datatype

```
#defining a function to detect if any spanish characters present in column names

def isEnglish(s):
    try:
        s.encode(encoding='utf-8').decode('ascii')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        dataC.append("`"+i.replace(" ", "_").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("/", "")+"`")
    else:
        dataC.append(i)

def isSpecialCharacters(s):
  special_characters = ['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','+','?','=','<','>','/']
  a_match = [True for match in special_characters if match in s]
  if True in a_match:
    dataD.append("`"+j.replace(" ", "_").replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("/", "")+"`")
  else:
    dataD.append(j)


import csv

# Open the file in 'r' mode, not 'rb'
csv_file = open('/dbfs/mnt/reservoir/Mapping_List.csv','r',encoding='latin1')
dataA = []
dataB = []
dataC = []
dataD = []
# Read off and discard first line, to skip headers
csv_file.readline()
# Split columns while reading
for a, b, c in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=','):
    # Append each variable to a separate list
    dataA.append(a)
    dataB.append(b)
#checking whether any spanish characters present in list
for i in dataA:
    isEnglish(i)
for j in dataC:
    isSpecialCharacters(j)
file_list=list(zip(dataD,dataB))
final_list=[]
for i,j in file_list:
    res=i+' '+j.upper()
    final_list.append(res)
result=','.join(final_list)
#print(result)
query="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  Mapping_List ({}) USING DELTA LOCATION '/mnt/reservoir/Mapping_List'".format(result)

sqlContext.sql(query)
```

while i create the table as below format its working fine:

```
%sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Mapping_List (
  code STRING,
  Name STRING,
  Group STRING,
  Year STRING,
  Trasm STRING,
  ID STRING,
  3_AVC_VFA STRING,
  3_AVC_TRA STRING,
  Code_1 STRING,
  Code_2 STRING,
  Code_3 STRING,
  Code_4 STRING,
  Code_5 STRING,
  Code_6 STRING,
  Code_7 STRING,
  Code_8 STRING,
  Code_9 STRING,
  Code_10 STRING
  )
USING DELTA
LOCATION '/mnt/reservoir/Mapping_List'
```

why am I getting the parse exception in first query?

Traceback error:

```
databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    452         [Row(f1=1, f2='row1'), Row(f1=2, f2='row2'), Row(f1=3, f2='row3')]
    453         """
--> 454         return self.sparkSession.sql(sqlQuery)
    455 
    456     def table(self, tableName):

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    775         [Row(f1=1, f2='row1'), Row(f1=2, f2='row2'), Row(f1=3, f2='row3')]
    776         """
--> 777         return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
    778 
    779     def table(self, tableName):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    121                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    122                 # JVM exception message.
--> 123                 raise converted from None
    124             else:
    125                 raise

ParseException: 
extraneous input 'STRING' expecting {')', ',', 'CONSTRAINT'}
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: What is the value of `query` when you get the error?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Mapping_List (code STRING,Name STRING,Group STRING,Year STRING,Trasm STRING,ID STRING,3_AVC_VFA STRING,3_AVC_TRA STRING,Code_1 STRING,Code_2 STRING,Code_3 STRING,Code_4 STRING,Code_5 STRING,Code_6 STRING,Code_7 STRING,Code_8 STRING,Code_9 STRING,
Code_10 STRING) USING DELTA LOCATION '/mnt/reservoir/Mapping_List'

Comment: @Barmar, have included the traceback now. Thanks!!

Comment: Have you compared that to the working query to see where they're different?

Answer (score 0):

The error `ParseException: extraneous input 'STRING' expecting {')', ',', 'CONSTRAINT'}` has occurred because the query that has been built has incorrect syntax.

- I have used the following queries for demonstration and got the same error:

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  demo3( id string, gname String string)")
```

[image]

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  demo3( id id String, gname String)")
```

[image]

There might be other possibilities as to why this error occurs. So, use `print(query)` to check what is the query that you are executing. Use the traceback error to identify the position where the error is occurring and correct it to overcome the error.